# How to find value of this series using python?

Tags: python, series, factorial

i m new to python and its great!. but i m facing difficulties in finding the result of this series:

```
 1-x+(x^2)/2!-(x^3)/3!+(x^4)/4!-..............up to n terms
```

what i wrote was:

```
  import math
  a=input("ENter the no")
  x=input("ENter value of x")
  i=1
  s=0
  s1=0
  s2=1
  p=1
  while(i<=a):
          if(i%2!=0):
                    s=s-math.pow(x,i)/p*i
          else:
                     s1=s1+math.pow(x,i)/p*i
          i=i+1
  else:
              s2=s2+s1+s
              print s2
```

please let me know of the correct program and the mistakes:)!! Thanks in advance.
let me know it without directly using the factorial function?

Comment: For starters, you are not calculating the factorial anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Taylor's series development of `exp(-x)`. Recognizing this gives you a good opportunity to check your result against `math.exp(-x)`.

### Simple syntax improvements

You don't need an 'else' after the while. Just add the code to be run after the loop at the same indentation level as before the while loop.

### Mathematical problems

Most importantly, the computing of the factorial is simply never done. Writing `p*i` does not store in p the product of p and i. You need to do that.

Then, there is a problem with the operator precedence. When you write `pow(...)/p*i`, Python understands `( pow(...) / p ) * i`, which is not what you mean.

Finally, most of the terms in the series cancel out, but you add all positive terms on one side and all negative terms on the other. This means that you will grow two very big values (and risk overflows if you were using integers), and then take the difference between them to get the result. Because double precision on a computer is finite, this is a bad practice precision-wise. It is better to keep all the terms in your sum with the same sort of orders of magnitudes.

### Improved for correctness

```
import math
a=input("Enter the no")
x=input("Enter value of x")
s=1
p=1
for i in range(1,a):
    p=p*i
    if(i%2!=0):
        s=s-math.pow(x,i)/p
    else:
         s=s+math.pow(x,i)/p
print s
print math.exp(-x)
```

Note how the use of a for loop and less intermedis-ry sums makes it all easier to read.

### Removing the branch

`pow(-x,i)` is negative if i is uneven, positive otherwise. Thus `-pow(x,i) if i%2 != 0 else pow(x,i)` can be rewritten `pow(-x,i)`. Removing an if in an inner loop is (almost ?) always a good thing, for performance. So a simplified version is :

```
import math
a=input("Enter the no")
x=input("Enter value of x")
s=1
p=1
for i in range(1,a):
    p=p*i
    s=s+math.pow(-x,i)/p
print s
print math.exp(-x)
```

That also has the benefit of making the code shorter (and thus more readable).

Answer (score 0):

```
import math    #imported to use the factorial function
def exp(x,n):
    ans = 1    #initializing it with 1 because the first term is a constant:1
    for i in xrange(1,n+1):   #starts looping from 1 to n terms 
        ans+=(-1**i*(float(x)**i)/math.factorial(i)) #changing the sign of 1, adding.
        # -1**i equals to 1 if i is even and -1 if i is odd
        # ** operator stands for the pow() function , (2**3 =8)
        # float(x) returns a floating value if value of x entered is integer
        # You can remove this is you are already entering floating values.
        # math.factorial() returns factorial of a given argument, 
    return ans
```

If you don't want to use the math.factorial() then you can try :

```
def exp(x,n):
    ans = 1
    dummy_factorial = 1
    for i in xrange(1,n+1):
        dummy_factorial*=i
        print dummy_factorial
        ans+=(-1**i*(float(x)**i)/(dummy_factorial))
    return ans
```

Comment: could you explain to me another way in which factorial function is  not used directly?Thank you

Comment: Now makes sense? @Animeartistfromhell7

Comment: did u use "dummy" to denote me?? anyway, its more better.

Comment: This not a platform to get personal about something, and dummy is used before any variable name which gets dissolved at the end of the program execution, it's just a convention, Sorry if that made you feel low, it was unintentional @Animeartistfromhell7

Comment: it doesnt matter.when i gave values for x:2,n:4...the answer should be 0 but i m gettin like -5.0...sorry for the trouble.